# unable to get all the layers in the .dlc format while doing .pb to .dlc conversion?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am running snpe-tensorflow-to-dlc command to convert my .pb file to .dlc. It runs successfully and converted my file to .dlc. But when I checked the information inside the file there was nothing there expcept input layers. No other layer was present. The command I used is given below:

```
snpe-tensorflow-to-dlc  --graph /home/shorav/snpe-1.18.0/models/graph.pb  
    -i  "input_1"  1,256,256,3  -i  "input_2"  1,256,256,3  --out_node  output_1  
    --dlc  graph2.dlc  --verbose
```

Please help me out I got stuck here ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the some of the network layer mentioned in your TensorFlow model are not supported by Qualcomm Neural Processing SDK.

You can find the Neural Processing SDK supported network layers from https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/snpe/network_layers.html